# How to create a neural network for regression?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I am trying to use Keras to make a neural network. The data I am using is https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Yacht+Hydrodynamics. My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from keras.models import Sequential
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

data = np.genfromtxt(r"""file location""", delimiter=',')

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, activation = 'relu', input_dim = 6))
model.add(Dense(1,))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics = ['accuracy'])

Y = data[:,-1]
X = data[:, :-1]
```

From here I have tried using model.fit(X, Y), but the accuracy of the model appears to remain at 0. I am new to Keras so this is probably an easy solution, apologies in advance.

My question is what is the best way to add regression to the model so that the accuracy increases? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

First of all, you have to split your *dataset* into `training` set and `test` set using `train_test_split` class from `sklearn.model_selection` library.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.08, random_state = 0)
```

Also, you have to `scale` your values using `StandardScaler` class.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)
```

Then, you should add more *layers* in order to get better results.

**Note**

Usually it's a good practice to apply following formula in order to find out the total number of *hidden* *layers* needed.

```
Nh = Ns/(α∗ (Ni + No))
```

where

- Ni = number of input neurons.
- No = number of output neurons.
- Ns = number of samples in training data set.
- α = an arbitrary scaling factor usually 2-10.

So our classifier becomes:

```
# Initialising the ANN
model = Sequential()

# Adding the input layer and the first hidden layer
model.add(Dense(32, activation = 'relu', input_dim = 6))

# Adding the second hidden layer
model.add(Dense(units = 32, activation = 'relu'))

# Adding the third hidden layer
model.add(Dense(units = 32, activation = 'relu'))

# Adding the output layer
model.add(Dense(units = 1))
```

The `metric` that you use- `metrics=['accuracy']` corresponds to a **classification** problem. If you want to do **regression**, remove `metrics=['accuracy']`. That is, just use

```
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam',loss = 'mean_squared_error')
```

[Here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/custom-metrics-deep-learning-keras-python/)  is a list of *keras* metrics for `regression` and `classification`

Also, you have to define the `batch_size` and `epochs` values for `fit` method.

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 10, epochs = 100)
```

[image]

After you trained your `network` you can `predict` the results for `X_test` using `model.predict` method.

```
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
```

Now, you can compare the `y_pred` that we obtained from neural network prediction and `y_test` which is **real** data. For this, you can create a `plot` using `matplotlib` library.

```
plt.plot(y_test, color = 'red', label = 'Real data')
plt.plot(y_pred, color = 'blue', label = 'Predicted data')
plt.title('Prediction')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

**It seems that our neural network learns very good**

Here is how the `plot` looks.
[image]

Here is the full code

```
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from keras.models import Sequential
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Importing the dataset
dataset = np.genfromtxt("data.txt", delimiter='')
X = dataset[:, :-1]
y = dataset[:, -1]

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.08, random_state = 0)

# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

# Initialising the ANN
model = Sequential()

# Adding the input layer and the first hidden layer
model.add(Dense(32, activation = 'relu', input_dim = 6))

# Adding the second hidden layer
model.add(Dense(units = 32, activation = 'relu'))

# Adding the third hidden layer
model.add(Dense(units = 32, activation = 'relu'))

# Adding the output layer

model.add(Dense(units = 1))

#model.add(Dense(1))
# Compiling the ANN
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')

# Fitting the ANN to the Training set
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 10, epochs = 100)

y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

plt.plot(y_test, color = 'red', label = 'Real data')
plt.plot(y_pred, color = 'blue', label = 'Predicted data')
plt.title('Prediction')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Beautiful answer !

Comment: Brilliant @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut, would you be able to explain the need for scaling?

Comment: @ES1927, many machine learning algorithms use Euler distance. So normalization or scaling is required so that all the inputs are at a comparable range.

Comment: I am having a bit of trouble with identifying what the x-axis represents in the predicted vs actual plot. First I thought it was the epochs, but within my data, it doesn't matter what I change in the epochs, I get the same x-axis range. Could someone please explain it to me?

Comment: Answering my own comment above, it is the sample number =)