# Keras Input Layer Shape On Input Layer Error

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to learn ai algorithms by building. I found a question on Stackoverflow which is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49008074/how-to-create-a-neural-network-for-regression).
I copied this code to try it out, and then modified it to this.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras as keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.python.keras import activations
# Importing the dataset
dataset = np.genfromtxt("data.txt", delimiter='')
X = dataset[:, :-1]
y = dataset[:, -1]

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.08, random_state = 0)

# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)



# Initialising the ANN
#model = Sequential()

# Adding the input layer and the first hidden layer
#model.add(Dense(32, activation = 'relu', input_dim = 6))

# Adding the second hidden layer
#model.add(Dense(units = 32, activation = 'relu'))

# Adding the third hidden layer
#model.add(Dense(units = 32, activation = 'relu'))

# Adding the output layer

#model.add(Dense(units = 1))
#model = Sequential([
#    keras.Input(shape= (6),name= "digits"),
#    Dense(units = 32, activation = "relu"),
#    Dense(units = 32, activation = "relu"),
#    Dense(units = 1 , name = "predict")##

#])
#
input = keras.Input(shape= (6),name= "digits")
#x0 = Dense(units = 6)(input)
x1 = Dense(units = 32, activation = "relu")(input)
x2 = Dense(units = 32, activation = "relu")(x1)
output = Dense(units = 1 , name = "predict")(x2)

model = keras.Model(inputs = input , outputs= output)
#model.add(Dense(1))
# Compiling the ANN
#model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')

# Fitting the ANN to the Training set
#model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 10, epochs = 200)

optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3)
loss = keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()

epochs = 200

for epoch in range(epochs):
    print("\nStart of epoch %d" % (epoch,))

    # Iterate over the batches of the dataset.
    for step in range(len(X_train)):

        # Open a GradientTape to record the operations run
        # during the forward pass, which enables auto-differentiation.
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:

            # Run the forward pass of the layer.
            # The operations that the layer applies
            # to its inputs are going to be recorded
            # on the GradientTape.
            logits = model( X_train[step] , training=True)  # Logits for this minibatch

            # Compute the loss value for this minibatch.
            loss_value = loss(y_train[step], logits)

        # Use the gradient tape to automatically retrieve
        # the gradients of the trainable variables with respect to the loss.
        grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_weights)

        # Run one step of gradient descent by updating
        # the value of the variables to minimize the loss.
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))

        # Log every 200 batches.
        if step % 200 == 0:
            print(
                "Training loss (for one batch) at step %d: %.4f"
                % (step, float(loss_value))
            )
            print("Seen so far: %s samples" % ((step + 1) * 64))


y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

plt.plot(y_test, color = 'red', label = 'Real data')
plt.plot(y_pred, color = 'blue', label = 'Predicted data')
plt.title('Prediction')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I modified the code for creating data when processing. If I use `model.fit`, it uses data I have given but I wanted to when epochs start to create data from a simulation and then process it.(sorry for bad english. if i couldn't explain very well)

When I start code in line 81:

```
Exception has occurred: ValueError
Input 0 of layer dense is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (6,)
```

It  gives an Exception. I tried to use `shape=(6,)` `shape=(6,1)` or similar to this but it doesn't fix anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a batch dimension when calling the keras model:

```
logits = model( X_train[step][np.newaxis,:] , training=True)  # Logits for this minibatch
```

A batch dimension is used to feed multiple samples to the network. By default, Keras assumes that the input has a batch dimension. To feed one sample, Keras expects a batch of 1 sample. In that case, it means a shape of (1,6). If you want to feed a batch of 2 samples, then the shape will be (2,6), etc.

Comment: Yey. That Worked. But Can You Explain A Little More What Is Batch Dimension? What We Use It For?

Comment: Thank You. When You Say Sample Are You Talking About How Much Data Inserted Or Data Processed At One Time? I Mean I Got 32 Float Coming From Different Stream To Feed. (1,32) Is Okay Or (2,16)Is Better? Sorry For This Idiotic Questions I Try To Understand Well